# Biopython CodonTable error?

Tags: python, biopython

I am writing some code intended to translate ambiguous DNA codes into possible amino acids and I am seeing some strange translation from the Biopython 1.56 package.  It appears to be translating ambiguous DNA codes to 'J' which does not exist as a code for anything.  I am running python 2.6.1 on Mac OS 10.6.6.

For example:

```
>>>from Bio.Seq import *
>>>translate('ARAWTAGKAMTA')
'XJXJ'
```

or

```
>>>from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>>c = Seq('ARAWTAGKAMTA')
>>>c.translate().tostring()
'XJXJ'
```

I have looked through the Bio.Data.CodonTable source and Bio.Seq source and I cannot find a reason why this would be happening.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: The expected outcome should be 'XXXX'.  I think the best answer came to my parallel post on biostar (http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/5688/biopython-translation-error). Although it still does not natively solve the issue, it is a work around I can live with for now.

Comment: +1 for the question, -1 because you could not find J is a well known letter to cope with L/I ambiguity in mass based sequencing methods. This equals zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J is Leucine (L) or Isoleucine (I), used in mass-spec (NMR).

See also http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/5688/biopython-translation-error